# connecting to Oracle from a Windows.Forms Application

Tags: c#, winforms, web-services, oracle, visual-studio-2012

I'll working in a Random Moment Sampling desktop app. I don't work with windows forms since a long time and I have the following questions.

1. I need to query data from Oracle 11g, if I remember right, before my users can start using the client application they need to install the oracle client. I'm right or this changed?
     
   If this is a problem I can use web services to retrieve the data. If someone has recommendations I'm open to alternatives, I'll have approximately 3000 users and I'm looking for the best option.
2. The application will run in the background querying the database every minute, it will look for samples, the moment it founds ones a window comes up blocking the computer until the user fills the sample.

   Is a Windows.Forms application the best option or I shall use Windows Service? I read a few threads but Im thinking in the installation process.

I'm currently on time so I can try a few ideas.

Comment: Do not use a Windows Service since your app requires interaction with the user.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes the Oracle software needs to be installed.  There is an "instant client" [package](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/instant-client/index.html) That is a little more lightweight then the normal client which can allow for connectivity.
2. Whether to use a service or not depends on the functionality of your system and how extensible you want it.  You mentioned you will have 300 users querying the data.  If they are querying the same data it may result in more than one user responding to the same data.  I don't know if this is what is desired.

edit: to combine a bit if the oracle software is a concern.  If you do create a service that serves up your data, the system where the service is run is the only one that will require the Oracle client software.

Comment: To add to your edit.  It will also be the only place that needs to be updated when there are database changes.  Layout, user id, password etc.